# Linked List Recursive Methods

Tags: list, recursion

I am trying to write a recursive method that inserts an element into a linked list via recursion.

```
/**
 * Insert the element in the list in non-decreasing order.
 */
public static List insert( int element, List list )
{
    // Implement.
}
```

The List class is as follows ( excluding getters/setters and other methods such as length( List l ) etc which I have already implemented ).

```
public class List
{
    int head;
    List tail;

    // Additional methods
}
```

I am having trouble getting my head around a recursive solution for this method and after much frustration I would appreciate some SO feedback.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
public static List insert( int element, List list )
{
   if(list == null)
      return new list(element, null);
   else{
      list.next = insert(element, list.next);
      return list
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.paulhorst.com/c241/linkedlist.htm

Here there's some information on how to handle linked lists and how to build the different methods involved.